# identity for finding value of $\pi$

Tags: pi, infinite-product, calculus

So in Euler's solution of the Basel problem he takes 
$\sin x= x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2}\right)\cdots$

well, i was playing around with it and put $ x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

After manipulating quite a bit,
$$\frac{2}{\pi}=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{(2*2)^2}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{(2n)^2}\right)\cdots$$
after simplifying a bit$$\frac{2}{\pi}=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(\frac{15}{16}\right)\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)\cdots$$

I tried evaluating LHS by hand, and the partial products slowly do decrease towards RHS, and we know that they will not decrease forever because $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2-1}{n^2}=1$$
so can anyone help by writing a program which can do partial sum up to high values of n and tell me if its true.
PS.I am in 10th standard do if im wrong anywhere please dont explain in too complicated mathematics. thanks

Comment: $\sin x$ cannot equal $\pi/2,$ which is greater than 1.

Comment: You actually put $x=\pi/2$, right?

Comment: 'Twas a typo, my bad sire.

Comment: It's a known result, [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), though Wallis didn't prove it that way (predictably, since he did so in 1655, long before Euler's results).

Comment: well, i couldn't find anything by "2/pi infinite product identity" on google so i posted it here. thank you for directing me.

Comment: i know how to prove the euler product identity i wanted to know if the identity i reached was true or if i made some mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac2{\pi} \approx 0.6366198$ is the correct limit of the product

As an illustration (not a proof) using R:

```
maxn  <- 2^15
plot(exp(cumsum(log(1 - (2*(1:maxn))^(-2)))), log="x")
abline(h=2/pi, col="red")
```

giving

[image]

Comment: thank you, for the program mister henry